What is the largest culturable bacterium?
E. coli is easy to grow in the lab. It has a volume around $0.6 \mu m^3$. Source
T. namibiensis can be much larger, with a volume on the order of ${10^6}\mu m^3$. Source
However, T. namibiensis is not easily cultured. Source
So, the question: what's the largest bacterium (or failing that, a large one) that can be cultured under standard lab conditions? Let's define 'standard lab conditions' as growing with a doubling time of <48h between 25C and 50C in a liquid media with normal oxygen.

It all depends on what you mean by standard lab conditions and largest - length, width, volume, genome size?. There are lots of bacteria that grow at odd conditions (e.g. anaerobic), but are perfectly easy to grow under those conditions. Try the spirochetes as examples.

Good point. Let's say: can grow with a doubling time of <48h between 25C and 50C in a liquid media with normal oxygen. And measuring largest by volume. Is there a spirochete that fits the bill here?

It would be a good idea to add those conditions to the question. Not sure on spirochetes doubling time, and I think anaerobic from memory.

You’ve put a bounty on this so I’ll have to wait to vote to close, but it’s a “Guinness Book of Records” question quite unsuited to this site and of no interest to professional biologists. There are microorganisms which one would have much more interest in culturing where the problem is far more subtle than size.

@David I disagree, and perhaps I need to add more context to the question to justify my interest. I am a professional microbiologist. IIRC, I posted this question after a journal club about a paper comparing cell sizes in eukaryotes and bacteria, and making some arguments about diffusion and the necessity of a nucleus after certain length scales—it referenced some large bacteria that could not be cultured, so I wondered whether there was a large bacterium that could make a good model for some of the questions they raised.

OK. But there is a reason that the guidelines on asking good questions tell you to provide context. And remember questions are also supposed to relate to "problems that you face". There is nothing in your question that indicates why you want to know this, and the site tends to attract "tourists" who have nothing better to do than ask GBR-type questions. I'll delete my comment when you have read it, but would suggest that you incorporate our remarks into the question.
